# Do we need open transaction multiple times or just once in start?

Tags: sql, transactions

Which method is better to use probably in case of python or laravel php or doesn't matter which ever technology it is as long as we use transaction, commit, rollack concepts...

**-- Method 1 --**

```
open transaction

execute sql code 1
commit or rollback

execute sql code 2
commit or rollback

close transaction
```

**-- Method 2 --**

```
open transaction
execute sql code 1    
commit or rollback
close transaction

open transaction
execute sql code 2    
commit or rollback
close transaction
```

Comment: It depends what you want to do.  The two are different.  Notably, if code2 fails, what happens to the changes effected by code1?

Comment: assuming code1, code2 are independent, no dependencies ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transaction is an atomic operation, meaning it can either completely succeed or completely fail.
You use transactions when you have two or more statements that are dependent on each other - for instance, If you have a sales database and you want to add an order with items, you will typically use a single transaction to add the order and all it's items - so if you failed to insert an item the entire order will then not be inserted to the database.

If your statements are independent, you do not need an explicit transaction at all.

BTW, You can only commit or rollback a transaction once, so the pseudo code in your first example will fail, since you try to commit/rollback the same transaction twice.

Comment: Thanks @zohar peled

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)